# How to use an if statement to break a while loop when the word exit is typed?

Tags: python, break

I want to make it so that when the word "exit" is typed the loop breaks and it prints a message. How do you do this?

This is the code I have so far:

```
file=open("C:/Users/wl/Documents/devices.txt","a")
while True:
    newItem = input('Input the new device:')
    
  
if newItem == 'exit':
```

I've tried putting a break after that last line but it won't work so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: in python block of code are determined by its indentation level, so if you want the if-statement to be inside the while loop you need to indent it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. "I want to make it so that when the word "exit" is typed the loop breaks" Think carefully about the intended logic. If the purpose of this code is to break the loop (conditionally), should it be inside the loop, or outside? Why? Currently, is the code inside the loop, or outside? How do you know? (Hint: what is the purpose of indentation in Python?) Do you see the problem?

Comment: "I've tried putting a break after that last line but it won't work" When something doesn't work, the first thing to do is *look at how* it doesn't work. Is there an error message? Then *read* and *try to understand* the error message. This one, presumably, says `break outside loop`. That gives you another hint to the problem. If `break` being `outside` the `loop` is a problem, then where should the `break` be instead?

Comment: Finally: if you do not understand what I mean about indentation, or about which code is inside or outside the loop, please try to learn the fundamentals first, by following a tutorial. If this code is already from working through a tutorial, please try to re-read the lesson. Failing that, you could contact the author, try to get help on an actual *discussion forum* such as Reddit or Quora, or look for a dedicated discussion forum for the tutorial you are using.

Comment: Another thing you can (and should) try doing is to [use the Internet to look for an existing solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) before asking. For example, by putting `python loop until user types exit` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+loop+until+user+types+exit), or [python break when user types exit](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+break+when+user+types+exit), or anything like that.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```py
newItem = str()
while newItem != "exit":
    newItem = input('Input the new device:')

print("'exit' was typed.")
```

Answer (score 2):

this is how you can achieve what you want with `break` statement:

```
while True:
    newItem = input('Input the new device:')
    if newItem.lower() == 'exit':
         print('your message')
         break
```